# How use jquery html() function and text() function

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted ***.dropdown-menu li child a*** is  appendTo ***.btnClass***
 how use html elements append to ***btnClass***.

```
<div class="input-group-btn">

<button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse">
    <span class="current" data-url="">Submenu1</span> <span class="right">&nabla;</span>
</button>

<ul id="categories" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="unicode ieUnicode">Submenu2 <br> <span>Counter Increment </span></a></li>
</ul>
```

1. i have this problem.

   [image]

   2. i wanted this style

[image]

how use appendTO html text

## [SEEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/67mwG/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use html instead of text:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
$('#categories li').click(function(){
    $('.input-group-btn').removeClass('open');
    $('.current').html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFNnY/).**

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` replaces all html contents which includes html elements, labels

whereas `.text()` will replace only labels, that labels include its descendent's label also.

You can replace html with selected li html like below :

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
$('#categories li').click(function(){
    $('.input-group-btn').removeClass('open');
    $('.current').html($(this).find('a').clone());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67mwG/3/)**

Or replace with li anchor html

```
$('#categories li').click(function(){
    $('.input-group-btn').removeClass('open');
    $('.current').html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67mwG/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
    $('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
$('#categories li').click(function(){
    $('.input-group-btn').removeClass('open');
    $('.current').html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you JS. Use the below:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
$('#categories li').click(function(){
    $('.input-group-btn').removeClass('open');
    $('.current').html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

In the last line you are using `.text()` as I have seen in fiddle, instead of that use `.html()` function.